# Java Pattern.matches() fails with long String

Tags: java, html, regex

I am trying to get an information out of a HTML source. When i Just test the right part of the source, everything works fine. But when I test the whole source, Pattern.matches() returns true even if it should match the pattern.

Doesn't work:

```
    String response = " <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\"     \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\"><html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"de\" lang=\"de\">  <head>      <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\" />      <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Language\" content=\"de\" />     <meta name=\"description\" content=\"arenakampf.de - Die Herausforderung\" />       <meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"Arenakampf, AK, arenakampf.de, Arena, Gilden, Kampf\" />          <link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"grafik/favicon.ico\" />              <link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"screen\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"css/reset.css\" />       <link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"screen\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"css/layout.css\" />      <link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"screen\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"css/content.css\" />     <link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"screen\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"css/jquery.ui.css\" />    <title>            Arenakampf - Die Herausforderung!    </title>       <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/jquery.js\"></script>     <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/jquery.ui.js\"></script>      <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/jquery.plugin.tablesorter.js\"></script>      <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/jquery.AK.functions.js\"></script>                                        <script type=\"text/javascript\">          var rTime = 0;      var pTime = 0;      var showTime = 0;      var name = \"Fredo\";      var d = new Date();      var rTime = Math.ceil(rTime);      var pTime = Math.ceil(pTime);      var startdate = Math.floor(d.getTime() / 1000);      var rTimeEnd = startdate + rTime;      var pTimeEnd = startdate + pTime;      var rTimerActive = window.setInterval(\"rTimer()\", 100);      var pTimerActive = 0;      var skyBannerAppear = 0;      var worldChat = 0;   </script>   <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/AK.WorldChat.js\"></script>     </head>  <body>       <div class=\"wrap\" >           <div class=\"root\">                <div class=\"top_header\">                  <a title=\"arenakampf.de\" href=\"?site=start\">                        <img src=\"grafik/background.top.jpg\" alt=\"Banner von Arenakampf.de\" />                  </a>                    <form method=\"post\" id=\"quickchange\" action=\"?site=overview\">                     <select name=\"quickchange\" onchange=\"javascript:document.getElementById('quickchange').submit()\"><option value=\"4339\">Aegis 100/100</option><option value=\"4340\" selected=\"selected\">Fredo 100/100</option><option value=\"4341\">Ymir 100/100</option><option value=\"4342\">Todos 100/100</option></select></form>                  <div class=\"information_header\">                      <div class=\"char_information\">                                                                                        Fredo<br />                             Zwerg, 7                                                        <div id=\"dek\">                                    <h2>Charakterinformationen</h2>                                 Regenerationszeit:  <span id=\"rcounter\">0:00</span><br />                                 Angriffsschutz: <span id=\"pcounter\">0:00</span><br />                                 Trefferpunkte: 106/106<br />                                                                                                Geld: 2n, 12k                               </div>                                                                                                  </div>                      <div class=\"message\">                         <a href=\"http://forum.arenakampf.de/showthread.php?p=66276#post66276\" target=\"_blank\"><font size=\"2\" color=\"#cccccc\"><b>Newsthread updated</b></font></a>                       </div>                      <div class=\"social_networks\">                         <a href=\"http://www.facebook.com/pages/Arenakampf/169687129766829?ref=hnav\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"ArenaKampf bei Facebook\">                              <img src=\"grafik/like_facebook.png\" alt=\"ArenaKampf bei Facebook\" />                            </a>                                <a href=\"https://plus.google.com/112562504705381850039?prsrc=3\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"ArenaKampf bei GooglePlus\">                                                                <img src=\"https://ssl.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-16.png\" alt=\"Arenakampf bei GooglePlus\" />                             </a>                            </div>                          <div class=\"online_counter\">                                           Online: 54,                            <a href=\"http://webchat.quakenet.org/?channels=arenakampf&uio=d4\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Offizieller irc-Webchat von Arenakampf\">Q-Net: #arenakampf</a>                       </div>                  </div>                          </div>              <div class=\"main\">                    <div class=\"navigation\">                                          <div class=\"status_bars\">                         <div id=\"health\"></div>                           <div id=\"ers\"></div>                          <div id=\"exp\" style=\"width: 73%;\">                                                                              </div>                      </div>                          <script type=\"text/javascript\">          hpwidth = 100;          erswidth = 100;          document.getElementById('ers').style.width = erswidth + '%';          document.getElementById('health').style.width = hpwidth + '%';          if (106 != 0) {            setInterval( \"if (hpwidth + 0.13888888888889 * 20 <= 100) {hpwidth += 0.13888888888889 * 20;document.getElementById('health').style.width = hpwidth + '%'}\", 20000);            setInterval( \"if (erswidth + 0.27777777777778 * 20 <= 100) {erswidth += 0.27777777777778 * 20;document.getElementById('ers').style.width = erswidth + '%'}\", 20000);          }        </script>                       <ul >           <li>        <a href=\"?site=messages&pmpage=pmentry\">Nachrichten</a>           </li>       </ul>               <ul>            <li>                    <a href=\"?site=overview\">Übersicht</a>      </li>      <li>        <a href=\"?site=editcharstats\">Werte</a>      </li>            <li>        <a href=\"?site=skills\">Fertigkeiten</a>      </li>      <li>         <a href=\"?site=achievements\">Erfolge</a>      </li>       </ul>                                       <ul>            <li>            <a href=\"?site=itemshop\">Waffenladen</a>          </li>       <li>            <a href=\"?site=itemshop&cat=magical\">Magieladen</a><br />             </li>       <li>            <a href=\"?site=matshop\">Materialladen</a><br />           </li>      </ul>              <ul>              <li>                        <a href=\"?site=gilde\">Gilde</a>         </li>        <li>             <a href=\"?site=worldchat\">Weltchat</a>                        </li>       <li>        <a href=\"?site=handel\">Marktplatz</a>         </li>       <li>            <a href=\"?site=crafting\">Werkstatt</a>        </li>      </ul>            <ul>        <li>            <a href=\"?site=kalender\">Kalender</a>         </li>      </ul>            <ul>        <li>            <a href=\"?site=fight\">Arena</a>       </li>       <li>            <a href=\"?site=battlelogs\">Kampfbuch</a>          </li>       <li>                        <a href=\"?site=money\">Kassenbuch</a>          </li>       <li>            <a href=\"?site=adressbook\">Kontaktbuch</a>        </li>       </ul>        <h2 id=\"section_spiel\">Spiel</h2>    <ul class=\"section_spiel\">        <li>            <a href=\"http://forum.arenakampf.de/showthread.php?t=4288\" target=\"_blank\">Regeln</a>                   </li>       <li>            <a href=\"?site=intro\">Intro</a>               </li>       <li>            <a href=\"?site=changes\">News</a>                  </li>       <li><a href=\"?site=umfrage\">Umfrage</a></li><li><a href=\"?site=messages&pmpage=newpm&toname=Support\">Support</a></li>   </ul>       <ul>        <li>            <a href=\"?site=faq\">Anleitung</a>                 </li>       <li>            <a href=\"http://forum.arenakampf.de/showthread.php?t=5151\" target=\"_blank\">Wegweiser</a>                    </li>       <li>                                <a href=\"?site=ipcalculator\">IP-Berechnung</a>                                        </li>       <li>            <a href=\"http://forum.arenakampf.de\" target=\"_blank\">Forum</a>      </li>       <li>            <a href=\"?site=impressum\">Impressum</a>       </li>   </ul>   <h2>Rankings</h2>   <ul>        <li>            <a href=\"?site=craftrank\">Handwerker</a>                          </li>       <li>            <a href=\"?site=guildrank\">Gilden</a>                  </li>   </ul><ul>   <li>        <a href=\"?site=account\">Einstellungen</a> </li>   <li>        <a href=\"?site=editchars\">Charakter</a>           </li></ul>      <ul>        <li>            <a href=\"?site=logout\">LOGOUT</a>         </li>       </ul>           </div>                          <script type=\"text/javascript\">                           setBackgroundAttachment();          </script>                       <div class=\"content\">                                 <br /><br />                  <h2 class=\"player_name\">Fredo</h2><br /><br /><table class=\"tabletop\" width=\"85%\">  <tr>    <td width=\"55%\">      <table class=\"tabletop2\" width=\"100%\">        <tr><td colspan=\"2\">Account</td></tr>        <tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">Name:</td>          <td width=\"45%\">eisfreak</td>        </tr>        <tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">Ruhmpunkte:</td>          <td width=\"45%\">8</td>        </tr>        <tr><td></td></tr>        <tr><td colspan=\"2\">Charakter&uuml;bersicht:</td></tr>        <tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">Name:</td><td width=\"45%\">Fredo</td></tr>        " +
            "<tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">Stufe:</td><td width=\"45%\">7</td></tr>" +
            "        <tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">Erfahrung:</td><td width=\"45%\">8899</td></tr>        <tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">Erfahrung bis zur n&auml;chsten Stufe:</td><td width=\"45%\">554</td></tr>        <tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">Geld:</td><td width=\"45%\"><small>2n, 12k</small></td></tr>        <tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">Beruf:</td><td width=\"45%\">arbeitslos</td></tr>        <tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">Berufserfahrung (Wert):</td><td width=\"45%\">0 <br /><small><i>(--- zu ---%)</i></small></td></tr>        <tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">Ranglistenplatz:</td><td width=\"45%\">---</td></tr>        <tr><td></td></tr>        <tr><td colspan='2'>Statistik:</td></tr>        <tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">K&auml;mpfe:</td><td width=\"45%\">93</td></tr>        <tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">Davon gewonnen:</td><td width=\"45%\">86</td></tr>        <tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">Davon verloren:</td><td width=\"45%\">7</td></tr>        <tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">Verh&auml;ltnis:</td><td width=\"45%\">92%</td></tr>       </table>    </td>    <td align=\"center\" class=\"centered\"><img src=\"charpics/nopic.gif\" class=\"playerpic\" alt=\"Charbild\" /></td>  </tr>  <tr>    <td width=\"45%\">      <table class=\"tabletop2\" width=\"100%\">         <tr><td colspan='2'>Resistenzen:</td></tr>        <tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">Hieb:</td><td width=\"45%\">10</td></tr>        <tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">Schlag:</td><td width=\"45%\">0</td></tr>        <tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">Stich:</td><td width=\"45%\">-10</td></tr>        <tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">Feuer:</td><td width=\"45%\">-10</td></tr>        <tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">Frost:</td><td width=\"45%\">-10</td></tr>        <tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">Licht:</td><td width=\"45%\">-10</td></tr>        <tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">Gift:</td><td width=\"45%...";
```

Does work:

```
String response = "<tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">Stufe:</td><td width=\"45%\">7</td></tr>";
```

Regex:

```
String attribute = "Stufe";         
String attributeValue;
if (source.matches("<tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">" + attribute + ":</td><td width=\"45%\">(.*?)</td></tr>")){
    attributeValue = source.replaceAll("<tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">" + attribute + ":</td><td width=\"45%\">(.*?)</td></tr>", "$1");
} else {
    attributeValue = "Error loading '" + attribute + "'";
}
```

Any suggestions what I can do against this? Is the string length really a problem?

Comment: You appear to be using the wrong tool for the job. In general you should not use regular expressions in place of an HTML parser such as JSoup.

Answer (score 1):

apart from sharing Hovercraft's opinion - JSoup is so wicked - you are not using matches properly. Matches ensures that the regex matches the entire string and does not check if the string *contains* the regex. I think you would need something like

```
source.matches(".*<tr class=\"tablemid\"><td width=\"55%\">" + attribute + ":</td><td width=\"45%\">(.*?)</td></tr>.*"))
```

this. You would have to double check the greedyness of `.*`. Even if this would work, the regular expression would need a whole lot of buffering, making it very slow. So have a go with Jsoup, I promise you will be pleased!

Comment: Why can't I upvote ur post :(
Thanks that was a very silly mistake. Now it works. I'll have a look into JSoup

Comment: But there's no way to manage cookies using jSoup right? So I should continune getting the source with HttpClient and than parse it with jSoup?

Comment: To be honest: I dont know. I would give it a try, if not you can continue to use HTTPClient from Apache. This can handle browser mimicking, authentication, session handling, persistent http connections, etc. Let HttpClient talk to the server, get the response from HttpClient and pass it to JSoup - be sure to pass a base url with the content. I've done this before, and it was very performant.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try on of the following  [Html Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/).

> HTML Parser is a Java library used to parse HTML in either a linear or nested fashion. Primarily 
>   used for transformation or extraction, it features filters, visitors, custom tags and easy to use 
>   JavaBeans. It is a fast, robust and well tested package.